# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' after Heroku Deployment

Tags: python, django, tkinter, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my Django Application on Heroku. After deployment, my app crashed and it gives the `No module name _tkinter` error. I am not using it, may be it's being used in some library or package. I have deployed a few apps before on Heroku but never got this error.

I also went through other answers but they are mostly associated with sudo etc. I am deploying it from windows. Please let me know on how to fix this, as I couldn't find any `_tkinter' package either.

Comment: _tkinter is used by tkinter. You aren't going to be able to run tkinter on a server. Tkinter requires a display, not a web browser.

Comment: just figure it out, I accidentally used `from turtle import distance` due to which this issue was being generated.